# Filter a list of addresses on a separate list of postcodes

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to filter a long list of addresses based on whether they contain any of a number of postcodes, how do I structure the SQL query?

Addresses look like this

```
+------------------------------------------+
|              address                     |
+------------------------------------------+
| 69, example entry road, London, wa13 657 |
| 87, example entry road, London, eC2B 984 |
+------------------------------------------+
```

Postcodes like this

```
+-----------+
| Postcodes |
+-----------+
| Wa13 657  |
| eC2B 984  |
| eq8 987   |
+-----------+
```

The address table has an `ID` column

The closest I have come is with the following;

```
SELECT p.Postcodes, COUNT(*)
FROM [City Postcodes] AS p 
INNER JOIN [17-18] AS a ON (a.[Address], p.Postcodes) > 0
GROUP BY p.Postcodes;
```

However, this just counts the occurrences of each postcode. What I'd really like to do is filter the address table and identify the IDs based on the postcodes, so I could take the ID's and work with the data in Excel.

Comment: Whats the problem with WHERE ... IN (...)?

Comment: `and identify the IDs` ... _which_ IDs?  I don't see any `ID` column mentioned in your query.

Comment: I'm really new to access and sql so havent worked out how to integrate the ID column, but the address table has one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you just want the `JOIN` without the aggregation?

```
SELECT a.*, p.Postcode
FROM [17-18] AS a INNER JOIN
     [City Postcodes] AS p
     ON instr(a.[Address], p.Postcodes) > 0;
```

You can add a `WHERE` clause if you only want particular post codes.

Note that this will not return addresses that don't match the post codes table.  If you want all addresses, use a `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you want all ids grouped by postal codes. You can do this using concatination functions or with Oracle, LISTAGG:

```
SELECT p.POSTAL, LISTAGG(a.ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY p.POSTAL) ids 
FROM Address a 
INNER JOIN Postcodes p ON a.POSTAL LIKE p.POSTAL 
GROUP BY p.POSTAL;
```

I've created a sql fiddle where you are able to test the code: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ca6844/1

- With mysql you can use group_concat:
  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat
- With SQL Server you can use Stuff() + string concatination: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017